# How to create a link with l() function that jumps to specific part of page?

Tags: theming, blocks

Hoping to create a link that jumps to a specific part of another page. For example in a block I have this:

```
<?php print l(t('About Me'), 'node/55#FIRST', array('absolute' => TRUE));?>
```

But in the browser it outputs the "#" as "%23":

```
http://www.site.or/node/55%23FIRST
```

Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last parameter of [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) accepts also the same options accepted from [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7). This means you can use the following code since Drupal 6.

```
<?php print l(t('About Me'), 'node/55', array('absolute' => TRUE, 'fragment' => 'FIRST')); ?>
```

On my test site, the output is the following one.

```
<a href="http://tero.local/dr72/node/55#FIRST">About Me</a>
```